# Can't see anything happening when I use ANTLR-made parser in C#

Tags: c#, antlr

I have some knowledge and skills in making translators and interpreters. But in every case I used a hand-written parser. Now I have a great idea to write an interpreter working through an own virtual machine on top of .NET, so it could use any of its reach API. Maybe a compiler into IL also is gonna appear. I decided to use ANTLR to boost developing speed and focus primarily on language and VM-code but not parsing. ANTLR - because I found in Wikipedia that it has an IDE and can generate parser code for C#, which I chose for writing my program.

After some efforts I have forced my code compile. Here's C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Resources;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using Antlr.Runtime;

class AgathaInterpretter
{
    static ResourceManager rm;
    static CultureInfo ci;

    static string GetString(string key)
    {
        try
        {
            return rm.GetString(key, ci);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return "Resource string not found.";
        }
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ci = new CultureInfo(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["locale"]);
        rm = new ResourceManager("Agatha.Messages", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        switch (args.Length)
        {
            case 0:
                Console.WriteLine(GetString("ERROR_COMMAND_LINE_ARGS_ZERO"));
                return;
            case 1:
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine(GetString("ERROR_COMMAND_LINE_ARGS_GREATER"));
                return;
        }

        StreamReader streamReader;
        try
        {
            streamReader = new StreamReader(args[0]);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(GetString("ERROR_SCRIPT_FILE_INACCESSIBLE"));
            return;
        }
        string str = "";
        while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
            str += streamReader.ReadLine() + "\n";
        Console.WriteLine(str);

        ANTLRStringStream Input = new ANTLRStringStream(str);
        AgathaLexer Lexer = new AgathaLexer(Input);
        CommonTokenStream Tokens = new CommonTokenStream(Lexer);
        AgathaParser Parser = new AgathaParser(Tokens);
        Parser.prog();
    }
}
```

And here's my grammar:

```
grammar Agatha;

options
{
    language=CSharp2;
}

tokens {
    PLUS    = '+' ;
    MINUS   = '-' ;
    MULT    = '*' ;
    DIV = '/' ;
    LP = '(' ; 
    RP = ')' ;
    SEMICOLON = ';' ;
    ASSIGN = '=';
}

public prog: statement+ ;

statement: assignmentExpression | SEMICOLON ; 

assignmentExpression    : ID ASSIGN additiveExpression SEMICOLON| additiveExpression SEMICOLON ;

additiveExpression: multiplicativeExpression ( ( PLUS | MINUS )  multiplicativeExpression )* ;

multiplicativeExpression: unaryExpression ( ( MULT | DIV ) unaryExpression )* ;

unaryExpression : LP assignmentExpression RP | NUMBER | ID; 


NUMBER  : (DIGIT)+ ;

WS : (' ' |'\t' |'\n' |'\r' )+ {skip();} ;

ID : ('a'..'z' |'A'..'Z' )+ ;

fragment DIGIT  : '0'..'9' ;
```

It seems to be valid, parser is generated. With my C# code posted first I tried to load different files and parse them with my prog(). But nothing happens if I also supply wrong source, no exceptions, no output to console. I would like to get some training first but can't get any. Where am I wrong? What's happening?

Comment: Actually I'm not sure what is *supposed* to be happening. The parsing seems to have no side-effects defined(?).

Comment: And what about parsing errors? Do I have to turn something on? At this point I just want to be able to validate source code fed to this parser.

Comment: I could not reproduce it (with the Java target). When testing with your XML-input file, I get a whole bunch of lexer- *and* parser errors. Btw, instead of creating a string from a file yourself, simply do: `new ANTLRFileStream(args[0])`

Comment: How do you get them? Are they thrown as an exception? Or simply written to standars output by the ANTLR-generated parser?

Comment: In the case of your grammar (and input) the lexer produces warning printed to the stdout, but continues tokenizing. The parser then throws an exception because the tokens are not as it expects.

Comment: Didn't understand you clearly. You mean something is written in stdout only if my grammar has code for this? And if I have wrong tokens, the parser automatically throws an exception if don't handle it in my grammar? This doesn't happen, why could it be so?

Comment: Just tried using new ANTLRFileStream(args[0]). No changes:(

Comment: I don't know why (I can't test the CSharp2 target on my Linux system). All I know is that if I run a parser generated from your grammar (with `language=Java`), errors and exceptions *are* being printed/thrown.

Comment: Well, I see that it's С# parser's feature. I have seen a post like mine here at StackOverflow, but I didn't find the anser there:(